# Как удалить с базы данных Realm 3.5.0

Tags: java, android, realm

Добрый день. У меня не получается удалить из базы данных нужную запись, которая была ранее добавлена.

```
    public class Receive extends RealmObject {

    private int ID;
    private String NAME;

    public int getID() { return ID; }

    public void setID(int ID) { this.ID = ID; }

    public String getNAME() { return NAME; }

    public void setNAME(String NAME) { this.NAME = NAME; }
}
```

Я создал приватный метод, который отвечает за удаления.

```
private void deleteRealm(int deleteId) {
    final RealmResults<Receive> results = realm.where(Receive.class).equalTo("ID", deleteId).findAll();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            results.deleteFromRealm(1); // Что сюда нужно передать, я не знаю.
        }
    });
}
```

Этот метод я привязал к обработчику.

```
Delete = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int editId = v.getId();
            deleteRealm(SityIDs[editId]); //Передаю ID записи.
        }
    };
```

Программа выдает ошибку, она связана в первую очередь с методом, который отвечает за удаление, после лог показывает, что ошибка возникала в обработчику  `Delete = new View.OnClickListener()`

Я так-же пробовал этот метод

```
final RealmResults<Dog> results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // remove single match
        results.deleteFirstFromRealm();
        results.deleteLastFromRealm();

        // remove a single object
        Dog dog = results.get(5); // Но я не знаю, что сюда нужно передать
        dog.deleteFromRealm();

        // Delete all matches
        results.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
});
```

Ошибка

```
07-22 20:59:41.251 25759-25759/ru.profgrammist.javaandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: ru.profgrammist.javaandroid, PID: 25759
                                                                             Theme: themes:{}
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmQuery io.realm.Realm.where(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at ru.profgrammist.javaandroid.Zakladka.deleteRealm(Zakladka.java:104)
                                                                                 at ru.profgrammist.javaandroid.Zakladka.access$100(Zakladka.java:26)
                                                                                 at ru.profgrammist.javaandroid.Zakladka$2.onClick(Zakladka.java:69)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21156)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: ну так добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: @mit, я дополнил вопрос логом

Comment: Ошибка означает, что у вас не инициализирован инстанс реалма, т.е. `realm = null`, покажите код, где вы инициализируете `realm`

Comment: `import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmResults;`
------

`public class Zakladka extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private Realm realm;
    ` Больше негде в этом классе

Answer (score 4):

Прежде чем использовать реалм, нужно получить инстанс, т.е. примерно так:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
      // здесь используете realm...
    } finally {
      realm.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Ну или можно привязать это к жизненному циклу активити\фрагмента как-то так:

```
private Realm realm;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    realm.close();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог данный метод удаления из официального источника Realm
private void deleteRealm(int deleteId) {

```
final RealmResults<Receive> results = realm.where(Receive.class).equalTo("ID", deleteId).findAll();

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                // remove single match
                results.deleteFirstFromRealm();
            }
        });
    }
```